# Is there a way to turn on ES6/ES7 syntax support in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

**Edit 3:  Starting in version 0.4.0, ES6 syntax can be turned on by adding a `jsconfig.json` file to the project folder with the following contents:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 2:  You can [vote](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752489-es6-es2015-support) for this feature on user voice**

---

Is there a way to "turn on" ES6/ES7 in Visual Studio Code?

[image: screenshot]

**Edit 1**

Tried @sarvesh's suggestion- overrode `javascript.validate.target` and restarted vscode.  Didn't help.

Comment: Would you mind putting it as an answer rather than an edit on your question?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Currently, the only way to use ES6 and ES7 features is to use [Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/).

On the other hand, [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752489-es6-es2015-support) you can see that there is a feature request for ES6 and ES7

Comment: Update: Looks ES6 will be available starting July 2015 - http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752489-es6-es2015-support

Comment: It seems pretty good. Still, there is work to be done in general.

Comment: I'm using the latest version `0.8.0` I still see error coloring for fat arrow functions... why?

Comment: @vanthome you need to indicate the files array you want to write with es6, check the link: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript

Comment: @TionXP you mean the approach with `jsconfig.json`? Well I did not try that but I expect this to work if I enable it globally. I don't want to tell VSCode file-by-file that I want to use ES6.

Comment: @vanthome Yeah, I haven't found a way to enable globally yet, let me know if you find something better.

Comment: @vanthome Also, there is not a way to enable for all the files inside a folder. Ex: es6/*.* You need to specify file by file. Really annoying.

Comment: Is there a place to vote for ES7 only? It is really frustrating not being able to use it at work because it doesn't support `async`

Answer (score 60):

It's quite easy, at the root of your project create a jsconfig.json file and write this object in it:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "commonjs"
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks!

Apparently they included this in vscode this summer:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vscode/archive/2015/07/06/vs-code-es6.aspx
So the answer above is no longer correct.

Comment: add `"experimentalDecorators": true` for es7 decorators

Comment: What about ES6 imports? Will debugging/break points work? Does not seem to work with `"module": "es2015"`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me I have this guys problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110019/es6-syntax-unrecognized-by-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 50):

This [link](http://donovanbrown.com/post/Enabling-jshint-es6-support-in-VS-Code) helped a lot. Adding the jsconfig.json file to the the project didn't help much or rather it's not the best solution. Go to file > preferences > settings. In the settings.json file add this line:

```
"jshint.options": { "esversion": 6 }
```

Also you can also enable this setting for the entire project by creating a `.jshintrc` file in your project's root and adding this content.

```
{
  "esversion": 6
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding to the above answers...

As per Docs of VS Code..

Make sure that you place the **jsconfig.json at the root** of your JavaScript project and not just at the root of your workspace. Below is a jsconfig.json file which defines the JavaScript target to be ES6 and the exclude attribute excludes the node_modules folder.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Here is an example with an explicit files attribute.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "files": [
        "src/app.js"
    ]
}
```

The files attribute cannot be used in conjunction with the exclude attribute. If both are specified, the files attribute takes precedence.

also try editing the **"target" property in tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",//es6
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What does this mean: "at the root of your JavaScript project and not just at the root of your workspace"?

Comment: Why can't vs code just pick up `.babelrc` etc? Why all the duplicated config? *grumbl*

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise you can use ESLint to highlight ES7 error (using babel parser or others): [VSCode Linter ES6 ES7 Babel linter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327096/visual-studio-code-linter-es7-babel-code/36327097#36327097)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use Flow instead of Typescript, which is much easier to setup and migrate to. I wrote a small article on [how to setup Flow with VS Code](https://medium.com/@peller/vs-code-javascript-validation-for-es7-49e8e3d64291).

Answer (score 0):

As of this date and according to the [ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) docs on the VSCode Marketplace, including a .eslintrc configuration file in the root of the project enables ES6 linting in the ESLint VSCode extension.

My .eslintrc config file looks like this:

```
extends:
  - standard
parser: babel-eslint
rules:
  object-curly-spacing: [ error, always ]
  react/prop-types: off
  space-before-function-paren: off
```

I have eslint installed via npm in node_modules and all I know is that with .eslintrc in the project root folder ES6 linting works and without it, it doesn't.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

To be more convenient. Set jsconfig.json in your folder.

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext"
    }
}
```