# ES6 support in VSCode isnt working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

Ive seen other questions regarding this issue - [Is there a way to turn on ES6/ES7 syntax support in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953293/is-there-a-way-to-turn-on-es6-es7-syntax-support-in-vscode) - but this has now been addressed by Microsoft and [implemented in VSCode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vscode/archive/2015/07/06/vs-code-es6.aspx).

However, I have downloaded the latest version of VSCode, and cloned the example es6 repo from [GitHub](https://github.com/jrieken/es6-vscode-sample), and it seems to not be working[image]

Comment: You will still need to target ES6 in your jsconfig.json.

Comment: I have have that file, it's in the example repo I cloned and am opening in the picture I posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn ES6/ES7 support, the best way is to use ESLint with dedicated parser ( babel, etc...). I try it if you're interested: [VSCode Linter ES6 ES7 Babel linter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327096/visual-studio-code-linter-es7-babel-code/36327097#36327097).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using eslint with npm, you may need the .eslintrc file in the root folder of your project. See my answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953293/is-there-a-way-to-turn-on-es6-es7-syntax-support-in-vscode/47698292#47698292) and the docs for the [ESLint VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint).