# VSCode Linter ES6 ES7 Babel linter

Tags: javascript, babeljs, visual-studio-code, eslint, ecmascript-2016

How to use Visual Studio code to lint JavaScript file based on babel/ES7 stage-0 rules?

I only need to lint code. I already have webpack transpiling Js file.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

How I proceed:

- install globally eslint : `npm install -g eslint`
- install babel-eslint : `npm install --save-dev babel-eslint`
- install eslint-plugin-react : `npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-react`
- create `.eslintrc` file in you root directory. here is my config:

```
{
"env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "es6": true,
        "jest": true,
        "jquery": true
    },
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "arrowFunctions": true,
            "binaryLiterals": true,
            "blockBindings": true,
            "classes": true,
            "defaultParams": true,
            "destructuring": true,
            "forOf": true,
            "generators": true,
            "modules": true,
            "objectLiteralComputedProperties": true,
            "objectLiteralDuplicateProperties": true,
            "objectLiteralShorthandMethods": true,
            "objectLiteralShorthandProperties": true,
            "octalLiterals": true,
            "regexUFlag": true,
            "regexYFlag": true,
            "spread": true,
            "superInFunctions": true,
            "templateStrings": true,
            "unicodeCodePointEscapes": true,
            "globalReturn": true,
            "jsx": true,
            "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
        }
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "strict": 0
    }
}
```

- In VSC, push <kbd>F1</kbd>, then write "extension", select "install extensions" and then, write "eslint" and validate. you will have to relaunch VSC
- In VSC code, open the user parameters (`settings.json`) and write:

```
{
    //disable default javascript validator replaced by eslint
    "javascript.validate.enable" : false 
}
```

Now, it should lint as wanted your ES7 code. If there is any issue with VSC reading eslint config, you can see it in the VSC console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>s
Shift</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>).

As a result, ES7 code (spread operator in objects for example) is well linted:
[image]

PS: may be my `.eslintrc` uses some useless extra data for ES7 linting so feel free to remove it :)

Comment: where should i put the .eslintrc file? in my home directory? or the "root" directory

Comment: In the root directory of your project, the one you select with VSCode when using 'openFolder'.

Comment: Thank you. Is this still the best way to go about it? VSCode threads on github hadn't been closed

Comment: Yes it is. I didn't find a better solution for now. VSCode team let me know that ES7 features was not in the pipe yet.

Comment: I followed all the steps, but at the end VSCode reported that eslint-plugin-react could not be found. It asked to install it globally so I better opted to install eslint as npm install --save-dev eslint. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. What about jshint plugin? Do you have only eslint for ES7 validation?

Comment: @SergeNikitin I never used jsHint. I use ESLint for JS validation & ReactJS validation.

Comment: `npm install --save-dev babel-eslint` isn't working for me - get an error message sayinv 'babel-eslint not found'. installing it globally as well worked though :(

Comment: @Philipp Kyeck i'm not sure to understand. You succeed to install it globally but not locally to your project?

Comment: installation works in both cases but VSCode only "finds" it when I install it globally.

Comment: what about formatter for the optional chaining? The standard one creates empty space between object and ? mark.

Comment: The built-n `tslint` from the JS language support built-in extension confused me. Had to turn it off, as the parsing and linting could be replaced by ESLint.

Answer (score 1):

Since the ESLint extension can use babel-eslint, install it and turn off vscode's built-in linting in user/workspace settings.

Here's an example setup using Create React App's eslint config + optional chaining:

`.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
  "javascript.validate.enable": false,
  "eslint.enable": true
}
```

`.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "extends": "react-app"
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
}
```

`.babelrc`:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"]
}
```

Here's all the npm packages to install for this setup:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-config-react-app babel-eslint@10.x @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin @typescript-eslint/parser eslint@5.x eslint-plugin-flowtype@2.x eslint-plugin-import@2.x eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@6.x eslint-plugin-react@7.x eslint-plugin-react-hooks@1.5.0 @babel/core @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining
```

> For those new to React or babel, unless you actually are using Create React App, you'll need a lot more babel config. Please only use the above as supplementary info and comment if you need help.