# Optional chaining operator support in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, babeljs

React Native 0.56 provides native support of `Optional Chaining Operator` i.e `?.`

However the latest stable release of VS Code can not recognize this syntax and throw a TypeScript validation error:

`[ts] Expression expected.`

while no complie-time or eslint error was thrown.

How can I do to fix it?

---

Update on 2019/12/11:

Optional chaining is offically supported by TypeScript since 3.7!

If you still meet this error, probably the TypeScript lib shipped with your VSCode is < 3.7.

You can fix it simply by installing the latest version of typescript (>= 3.7) to your workspace. (by npm or yarn as dev deps)

Then open the command palette, type `tstv`, and switch the *TypeScript version used for JS and TS features* from **VS Code's Version** to **Workspace's Version** (make sure it's >= 3.7) and voila!

This is definitely an awesome feature, thanks your all and happy hacking!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36327097/5735864) and [this tutorial](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/getting-eslint-right-in-react-native-bd27524cc77b) helped me to solve this problem. I think the key here is disabling js/ts validation since the error comes from specifically '[ts]'.

Comment: It's considered bad form to ask a question on SO and then fail to accept any of the valid answers. Please pick the most useful answer and mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

VS Code 1.41 [supports optional chaining](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_41#_optional-chaining-support-for-javascript-and-typescript) in both JavaScript and TypeScript files. This support includes syntax highlighting and IntelliSense.

If you are using VS Code 1.41+ and optional chaining is not working as expected, try:

- Check your installed extensions. Some of them may not yet understand optional chaining, which could cause errors or bad syntax highlighting
- If you are [using a workspace typescript version](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-newer-typescript-versions), make sure it is TypeScript 3.7+

Comment: No need to use the nightly build, you can also force VS Code to use the version in node_modules. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-newer-typescript-versions

Comment: In my case, I had typescript working but there was no info when hovering on the `?.prop`, and the debug console threw an error when trying to enter in a value with optional chaining. Some research showed that this is a [Node 14.5+ feature](https://node.green/#ES2020-features-optional-chaining-operator------optional-property-access), so I switched to using that version of node and now hovering works and the debug console now lets me use `?.` in expressions.

Answer (score 15):

You can install [JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next), then reopen VSCode.

Comment: Thank you! By far this is the godsend suggestion. Turning off TS validation was a lame option since you'd lose all the benefits of VSCode.

Answer (score 2):

I just resolved the issue with disabling js/ts validation in vscode json settings:

`"javascript.validate.enable": false`

You my need to install `eslint-plugin-babel` for eslint rules.

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "babel"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "babel/new-cap": 1,
    "babel/camelcase": 1,
    "babel/no-invalid-this": 1,
    "babel/object-curly-spacing": 1,
    "babel/quotes": 1,
    "babel/semi": 1,
    "babel/no-unused-expressions": 1,
    "babel/valid-typeof": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to your github repo for this? Be nice to see some boilerplate that's actually working

Comment: Just leaving this here for others. https://github.com/malienist/default-config-files/blob/master/.eslintrc.json

Answer (score 1):

This was still happening to me until I uninstalled the extension [JavaScript and TypeScript IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sourcegraph.javascript-typescript)

So yes, check uninstalling old plugins if you are still having this issue. Also you can try the [vscode insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) version and check if this works in that one. It worked for me without doing any change.

Comment: i'm glad i could help! thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

My case, i need add `"tslint-config-prettier"` to `tslint.json` file

This is my `tslint.json` file

```
{
  "defaultSeverity": "error",
  "extends": [
    "tslint:recommended",
    "tslint-config-prettier"  # ----> This line
  ],
  "jsRules": {},
  "rules": {
    "semicolon": false,
    "quotemark": [true, "single"],
    "prefer-for-of": false,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "interface-name": false,
    "callable-types": false,
    "no-console": false,
    "no-bitwise": false,
    "variable-name": [
      true,
      "allow-leading-underscore",
      "allow-snake-case"
    ]
  },
  "rulesDirectory": []
}
```