# How to use Optional Chaining in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, protractor

I want to change how object is filled with properties.

Currently I have

```js
export interface INewOffer {
    employment?: IEmployment;
    heightWeight?: IHeightWeight;
}

export interface IEmployment{
    trainings?: string;
    activeEmployment?: string;
    wage?: string;
}
```

And function which creates an object looks like this:

```js
private dataGenerator(newCustomer: INewCustomer): INewOffer {
    const data: INewOffer = {};
    if (NullCheck.isDefinedOrNonNull(newCustomer.age)) {
        data.employment = {
            trainings: newCustomer.trainings,
            activeEmployment: newCustomer.activeEmployment,
            wage: newCustomer.wage,
        };
    } else {
        data.employment = {
            wage: newCustomer.wage,
            };
        }
    data.heightWeight = {
        height: '180',
        weight: '75',
    };
    return data;
}
```

I have tried to change my code to

```js
private dataGenerator(newCustomer: INewCustomer): INewOffer {
    const data: INewOffer = {};
    if (NullCheck.isDefinedOrNonNull(newCustomer.age)) {
            data.employment.trainings = newCustomer.trainings;
            data.employment.activeEmployment = newCustomer.activeEmployment;
            data.employment.wage = newCustomer.wage
    } else {
           data.employment.wage = newCustomer.wage
    }
    data.heightWeight.height = '180';
    data.heightWeight.weight = '75';

    return data;
}
```

and VS code IDE does not see any issues e.g: when I mouse over the:

- `data.` it says `const data: INewOffer`
- `employment.` => `(property) INewOffer.employment?: IEmployment`
- `wage` => `(property) IEmployment.wage?: string`

but when I run test I have error:

`E/launcher - Error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'wage' of undefined`

I have tried setting it like:
`data.employment!.wage = newCustomer.wage`

but it does not work. Then I have found out that there is no support in typescript for Optional Chaining.

and my question is, why IDE does not says its an error? or maybe I have to do something else to make it work?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741333/optional-chaining-operator-support-in-vscode with v1.41

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure to enable [`--strictNullChecks`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#--strictnullchecks), a [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).  Presumably you've got a [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) file in your project; you should specify it there.  In fact, I recommend using `--strict`, which includes `--strictNullChecks` plus other helpful stuff.  That should hopefully start warning you with errors like this:

```
   data.employment.wage // error!
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Object is possibly undefined.
```

Adding the exclamation point will not help; it is a [non-null *assertion*](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator), which means you are telling the compiler that even though *it* thinks the object might be undefined, *you* are sure that it's not.  This is basically the opposite of the problem you have.  If you do this:

```
   data.employment!.wage // no error now
```

it will *suppress* the error that `--strictNullChecks` turns on, but explode at runtime since you lied to the compiler.  That assertion is meant for situations like this:

```
// this ends up setting data.employment to {} but the compiler doesn't realize it
   Object.assign(data, { employment: {} }); 

   data.employment.wage // error!  but we know it *is* defined
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Object is possibly undefined.

   data.employment.wage // no error now
```

---

TypeScript's type system exists only at design time (when you write the program) and is completely [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) from the emitted JavaScript that runs.  If you want a runtime check to happen, you need to write that runtime check, and let TypeScript's type checker verify that you have done so:

```
  data.employment = {}; // set the property in a way the compiler recognizes
  data.employment.wage; // no error now
```

TypeScript *does* try to provide implementations for proposed JavaScript features, and there may eventually be support for [optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) in JavaScript, but the current proposal is only at [Stage 1](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/), and the TypeScript maintainers' general policy is only to implement language additions once they reach Stage 3.  So TypeScript doesn't support optional chaining [yet](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16) as of TS3.4.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you a lot for clarification that is exactly what I was looking for.
I could addd that in my tsconfig file I have:
`"strict": true,` but also  `"strictNullChecks": false,`

Answer (score 2):

Finally typescript supports optional chaining - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html

So you could update the typescript version to **3.7** or later and update the version of vscode to make it working.