# VSCode doesn't understand React Fragment <></>, doesn't recognize newer ES syntax (.?)

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: the .? operator]

I am running vscode version 1.39.2. The Syntax highlighting messes up for React fragments and new ES syntax.

Comment: What is the source of the errors? Is it VS Code itself or something like eslint? Does this still happen if you disable all of your installed extensions?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

VSCode [supports JSX fragment syntax](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_19#_jsx-fragment-syntax). This problem is likely related to an extension in OP's editor. I found that disabling [Babel ES6/ES7](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dzannotti.vscode-babel-coloring) `v0.0.4` alleviated this issue for me.

As for the second issue, the latest stable release of VSCode `v1.40.0` doesn't support syntax highlighting for optional chaining (i.e. `?.`), but the next minor version `v1.41` will include it. In the meantime, there are other options you have for adding this feature, detailed by Matt Bierner [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58530234/2383178).

Comment: VS Code support JSX fragments in both JavaScript and TypeScript out of the box

Comment: I hope that my edit helps alleviate your concerns, Matt.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. No need to for the complications though: JSX fragment syntax is been supported for both JS and TS for two years now. The TypeScript server powers IntelliSense for both JS and TS which is what that release notes are referring too.

However you are correct that the OP's issue was almost certainly caused by that outdated extension

Comment: Thanks! The Babel plugin was the issue in my case also. Disabling it did the trick!

Comment: Disabling babel helped with Fragment but the .? still messed up.

Comment: I completely overlooked that part of the question. Updated my answer with that info.

Comment: Same error here. Disabling Babel ES6/ES7 fixed the highlighting, otherwise, instead of using the <> notation for fragments you can use the old notation <React.Fragment>  and the red highlighting errors should go away

Answer (score 10):

Disabling Babel E6/E7 extension in VScode worked for me.