# How can I make VSCode maintain proper syntax highlighting for .JS files after using Elvis (?) operator?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, babeljs, option-type

In my `.js` files, when I use an elvis operator `const something = data?.info?.set` , the entire file turns red after the line used.

How can I make VSCode recognize elvis operators and maintain syntax proper highlighting?

Note: I use `metro-react-native-babel-preset` and eslint, which by default allows for optionals in pure .js files (not typescript)

I have installed https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next and also followed the instructions to enable it. However, my code is still pure *red* color starting the line after I use the `?` operator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a null-coalescing (Elvis) operator or safe navigation operator in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613952/is-there-a-null-coalescing-elvis-operator-or-safe-navigation-operator-in-javas)

Comment: [The optional chaining operator proposal is at Stage 4 and thus will likely be in ECMAScript 2020](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining).

Answer (score 6):

VS Code 1.41 supports syntax highlighting and IntelliSense for optional chaining (`?.`) out of the box.

If you still see red highlighting with VS Code 1.41, either:

- One of your installed extensions is causing this. ESlint for example
- You are [using an older typescript version](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-newer-typescript-versions) in your workspace. Make sure to use TS 3.7+

Comment: TS 3.7.3, VSCode 1.41, ESlint disabled, it's still throwing off syntax highlighting :-/  I've restarted both VSCode and the Typescript server.

Comment: Try disabling your other extensions too, such as the Babel one

Comment: "Sublime Babel" was the problem. Thank you !

Comment: For me, this was caused by the old "JavaScript and TypeScript IntelliSense" plugin, which is not even necessary anymore.

Comment: Babel ES6/ES7 extension for VSCode was the culprit for me.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved by removing this plugin from VSCode :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After OP's edit of the question, I tried to scour for some info. This is what I came up with:

- [Getting eslint right in React Native](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/getting-eslint-right-in-react-native-bd27524cc77b)
- [VSCode Linter ES6 ES7 Babel linter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327096/vscode-linter-es6-es7-babel-linter/36327097#36327097)
- [Optional chaining operator support in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741333/optional-chaining-operator-support-in-vscode)

---

I don't believe there's an Elvis operator in JS.

Instead, you can use the OR operator to return something specific without crashing it. So something like

```js
const something = data.info.set || undefined;
```

Comment: I use react-native, and by default, it allows the usage of it due to the plugins it installs.

Comment: I've updated my answer to hopefully point you in the right direction. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Disable or remove this extension completely from your vs code

[The Extension causing the syntax error, hopefully, it works for you as it did for me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMQPA.jpg)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33805512)