# ES6 syntax unrecognized by Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

The application runs fine with nodejs v4.2.1, but I cannot get Visual Studio Code to recognize ES6 syntax, like `class`. Is there any extra configuration to get ES6 syntax recognized at design time by Visual Studio Code?

*./root/dir/task.js*

```
'use strict'

class Task { // <-- Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word (undefined)
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.completed = false;
  };

  complete() {
    console.log('Completing: ' + this.name);
    this.completed = true;
  };

  save() {
    console.log('Saving: ' + this.name);
  };
}

module.exports = Task;
```

I also have a `jsconfig.json`, as [this page suggests](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript).

*./root/jsconfig.json*

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "commonjs"
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of the latest version of visual studio code.. ( December release) ES6 support is primary. Means no need for jsconfig.json. 
Which version of code your are using?

Refer https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/ ( ES6 is new default ).

Some time back, code need jsconfig.json for every sub folders in your project for syntax highlighting.

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm on that version, and I do have syntax highlighting and suggestions through intellisense as I type. It even suggests `class` as I start typing it... it just underlines it after it's completely typed out.

Comment: Have you installed any extended vs code plugins ? If so can you disable that and try restarting the code ? Check now