# Node.js - success from command line but error from vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've just upgraded node from v0.10.* to v4.7.7 and I have an es6 code in my node.js app:

```
class Myclass {
}
```

and when typing from command line:

```
node --debug-brk=6648 --nolazy --harmony bin/www
```

App is running successfully:

```
Debugger listening on port 6648
```

When trying to start debug from vscode (with the exact same execution line!!!):

```
class Myclass {
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

Why ?

EDIT 1:
I DO have this section in my `jsconfig.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
}
```

Comment: what is vscode and how it's related to nodejs or js?

Comment: probably related if not duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953293/is-there-a-way-to-turn-on-es6-es7-syntax-support-in-vscode