# jshint error when using template strings in VSCode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, jshint

I'm using Visual Studio Code (1.6.1) with its jshint extension (0.10.15).

When I type some template string, such as:

```
console.log(`My name is: ${name}`);
```

VSCode highlights it in red and says:

```
[jshint] Unexpected '`'. (E024)
```

And the rest of the code starts showing dozens of false errors like:

```
[jshint] Expected an identifier and instead saw 'if'. (E030)
[jshint] Expected an operator and instead saw '('. (E030)
[jshint] Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. (W030)
```

I've looked in the docs, but nothing references this issue.

**Anyone come up with a workaround for this?**

Comment: Yeah, that because you are using `ES6`..jshint do not support `ES6` yet, and that is why it fails to recognize valid `ES6` syntax....

Comment: Yes it does.. then why `"esversion": 6` is even an option?

Comment: You can check the answers here and try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953293/is-there-a-way-to-turn-on-es6-es7-syntax-support-in-vscode

Comment: It is not VSCode who fails recognising template strings but jshint (I tried adding jsconfig just in case but nothing changed)

Comment: Then you need to wait for an update that fixed the issue...my bad

Comment: The config file is `.jshintrc`, not `jsconfig`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your JSHint is not recognicing ES6.

Can you try to set `esversion` to `6` in JSHint options?

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.7.1, with jshint extension 0.10.15. Without `.jshintrc` I got this message:

`[jshint] 'template literal syntax' is only available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6'). (W119)`

I created a `.jshintrc` file with content:

```
{
    "esversion": 6
}
```

And it worked.

Note that jshint module might be required (globally or locally), it can be automatically added to your `package.json` by doing:

`npm install --save-dev jshint`

This installs jshint locally (in `node_modules` folder) and adds a dev dependency entry:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "jshint": "^2.9.4"
  }
```

Note also that a restart of VS Code may be required, after installing the module or the extension.

Comment: Adding `"esversion": 6` to .jshintrc didn't do the trick :( (even restarted vscode just in case)

Comment: This worked for me, using VS Code `1.7.1` and jshint `0.10.15`

Comment: What version of jshint do you have in your package.json?

Comment: Don't have it there, I just installed the vscode extension (0.10.15)

Comment: After installing it: jshint@2.8.0

Comment: And after restarting vscode is working.. thanks mate you saved my day :) (a little suggesion: add to your answer this last 2 steps, installing jshint and restarting)