# How to support ES7 as static syntax in vscode’s JavaScript Standard Style Extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

How to support ES7 as static syntax in vscode Javascript Standard Style Extensions?

VSCode extension to integrate JavaScript Standard Style into VSCode.

Comment: What's your actual code without VSCode popups PS: `state` is not a static field.

Comment: Duplicate question. Check this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953293/is-there-a-way-to-turn-on-es6-es7-syntax-support-in-vscode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to turn on ES6/ES7 syntax support in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953293/is-there-a-way-to-turn-on-es6-es7-syntax-support-in-vscode)