# Deduplicate items in object - lost data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this as an object (indiErr):

```
[
  { errorType: 'color-contrast', errorImpact: 'serious', errorCount: 8 },
  { errorType: 'heading-order', errorImpact: 'moderate',  errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'image-alt', errorImpact: 'critical', errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'image-redundant-alt', errorImpact: 'minor', errorCount: 1},
  { errorType: 'landmark-no-duplicate-contentinfo', errorImpact: 'moderate', errorCount: 1},
  { errorType: 'landmark-unique', errorImpact: 'moderate', errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'link-name', errorImpact: 'serious', errorCount: 7 },
  { errorType: 'meta-viewport', errorImpact: 'critical', errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'region', errorImpact: 'moderate', errorCount: 30 },
  { errorType: 'tabindex', errorImpact: 'serious', errorCount: 18 },
  { errorType: 'color-contrast', errorImpact: 'serious', errorCount: 28 },
  { errorType: 'landmark-one-main', errorImpact: 'moderate', errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'page-has-heading-one', errorImpact: 'moderate', errorCount: 1
  }
]
```

With the following code I deduplicate items and sum the errorCount:

```
 const holder = {};

 indiErr.forEach(function(d) {
     if (holder.hasOwnProperty(d.errorType)) {
         holder[d.errorType] = holder[d.errorType] + d.errorCount;
         // d.errorImpact= d.errorImpact
         // holder[d.errorImpact] = d.errorImpact
 } else {
     holder[d.errorType] = d.errorCount;
     // d.errorImpact= d.errorImpact
     // holder[d.errorImpact] = d.errorImpact
   }
 });

console.log('holder:', holder)
const obj2 = [];

for (const prop in holder) {
  obj2.push({ errorType: prop, errorCount: holder[prop] });
 }

console.log('Error Object:', obj2);
```

In the deduplication the values for 'errorImpact' get lost. This is the result:

```
Error Object: [
  { errorType: 'color-contrast', errorCount: 36 },
  { errorType: 'heading-order', errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'image-alt', errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'image-redundant-alt', errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'landmark-no-duplicate-contentinfo', errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'landmark-unique', errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'link-name', errorCount: 7 },
  { errorType: 'meta-viewport', errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'region', errorCount: 30 },
  { errorType: 'tabindex', errorCount: 18 },
  { errorType: 'landmark-one-main', errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'page-has-heading-one', errorCount: 1 }
]
```

*(color-contrast is deduplicated, and errorCount is summed to: 36)*

Is there any way to change the forEach function to also push 'errorImpact' value to 'obj2'?
Have tried several things, but am stuck. Also don't know where to search for to solve this. Hope you have some pointers. Tnx!

I would like to have this as result:

```
[
  { errorType: 'color-contrast', errorImpact: 'serious', errorCount: 36 },
  { errorType: 'heading-order', errorImpact: 'moderate',  errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'image-alt', errorImpact: 'critical', errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'image-redundant-alt', errorImpact: 'minor', errorCount: 1},
  { errorType: 'landmark-no-duplicate-contentinfo', errorImpact: 'moderate', errorCount: 1},
  { errorType: 'landmark-unique', errorImpact: 'moderate', errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'link-name', errorImpact: 'serious', errorCount: 7 },
  { errorType: 'meta-viewport', errorImpact: 'critical', errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'region', errorImpact: 'moderate', errorCount: 30 },
  { errorType: 'tabindex', errorImpact: 'serious', errorCount: 18 },
 
  { errorType: 'landmark-one-main', errorImpact: 'moderate', errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'page-has-heading-one', errorImpact: 'moderate', errorCount: 1
  }
]
```

Comment: what do you mean by push errorImpact. do you want to count based on both errorImpact and errorType

Comment: holder should be an object literal instead of a dictionary so that you can assign the errorImpact value

Comment: @cmgchess : added the desired result. Only count 'errorCount'.

Comment: @nicolascolman : you mean const holder = ``   ?

Comment: @JanWillem Actually, it's an array const holder = [];
Then you have to add as many objects as you need with the format { errorType: '...', errorImpact: '...', errorCount: ... }

Comment: @JanWillem https://codeshare.io/pqVANX this is something like what nicolascolman was refering to. there are also shorter ways of doing this

Comment: @cmgchess and nicolascolman : thanks both. The codeshare code works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group objects by multiple properties in array then sum up their values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46794232/group-objects-by-multiple-properties-in-array-then-sum-up-their-values)

Answer (score 2):

this did the trick:

```
const holder = {};

 indiErr.forEach(function(d) {
     if (!holder.hasOwnProperty(d.errorType)) {
         holder[d.errorType] = {errorImpact: d.errorImpact, errorCount: 0};
        }
    holder[d.errorType].errorCount+=d.errorCount
 });

console.log('holder:', holder)
const obj2 = [];

for (const prop in holder) {
  obj2.push({ errorType: prop, ...holder[prop] });
 }

console.log('Error Object:', obj2);
```

Comment: That's a good use of spread operator. Congrats

Answer (score 0):

```js
const errors = [
  { errorType: 'color-contrast', errorImpact: 'serious', errorCount: 8 },
  { errorType: 'heading-order', errorImpact: 'moderate',  errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'image-alt', errorImpact: 'critical', errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'image-redundant-alt', errorImpact: 'minor', errorCount: 1},
  { errorType: 'landmark-no-duplicate-contentinfo', errorImpact: 'moderate', errorCount: 1},
  { errorType: 'landmark-unique', errorImpact: 'moderate', errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'link-name', errorImpact: 'serious', errorCount: 7 },
  { errorType: 'meta-viewport', errorImpact: 'critical', errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'region', errorImpact: 'moderate', errorCount: 30 },
  { errorType: 'tabindex', errorImpact: 'serious', errorCount: 18 },
  { errorType: 'color-contrast', errorImpact: 'serious', errorCount: 28 },
  { errorType: 'landmark-one-main', errorImpact: 'moderate', errorCount: 1 },
  { errorType: 'page-has-heading-one', errorImpact: 'moderate', errorCount: 1
  }
];

let r = {};
errors.forEach(({errorType,errorImpact,errorCount})=>
  (r[errorType]??= {errorType, errorImpact, errorCount:0}).errorCount += errorCount);
console.log(Object.values(r));
```

Comment: Tnx Andrew, the duplication breaks when I use this.  (Had to remove the '??'  because got this error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?').

Comment: @JanWillem does it not work when you click "Run code snippet"? You just have an older dev environment without new javascript features. Does it work if you replace `??=` with `||=`?

Comment: tnx, I see that 'Snippet' works which is great. I am on Node14. Turned types off, just want javascript. When I use:  ' || = '  I get error in Vscode Expression expected. If you have another suggestion, very interested!

Comment: @JanWillem see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953293/is-there-a-way-to-turn-on-es6-es7-syntax-support-in-vscode for turning on ES7 language features. I'm not familiar with vscode so I can't guide you specifically.